# dirty bit on C: after uninstalling KB2823324

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I've got 3 Windows 7 64 bit systems that installed the MS KB2823324 update and all have the dirty bit set in drive C:.... I uninstalled the KB and rebooted.  The OS saw the dirty bit and tried to run chkdsk but it failed saying that due to an uninstalled software it could not do the chkdsk.
system boots up fine afterwards but still cannot do defrag.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a coincidence that you were doing updates but it sounds like there could potentially be a problem on the disk.  This should go without saying but be sure to **IMMEDIATELY** back up anything of importance, if nothing else it is always good to have backups.

I would suggest testing the Hard Drive to ensure it isn't failing.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives. My favorite is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other health checks in the process.